# Cursor Trigger - A cursor with name mycursor doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursor

As I try to insert into table it gives error SQL Server throws an error:

> A cursor with name mycursor doesn't not exist.

Here are my codes

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_cr_groups]
   ON  [dbo].[masterheader]
   AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    Declare @mhID tinyint
    Select @mhID=masterheaderID from inserted
    Declare @mhcode nvarchar(50)
    Select @mhcode=masterheadercode from inserted
    Declare mycrusor CURSOR FOR SELECT masterheaderID, masterheadercode FROM inserted;
    open mycursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor into @mhID, @mhcode;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    Begin
        IF  @mhcode='INC'
        Begin
            insert into groups
            Values
            ('Groupnameone','GRP-1',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnametwo','GRP-2',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnamethree','GRP-3',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1)
        End
        Else IF @mhcode='EXP'
        Begin
            insert into groups
            Values
            ('Groupnamefour','GRP-4',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnamefive','GRP-5',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnamesix','GRP-6',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1)
        End
        Else IF @mhcode='AST'
        Begin
            insert into groups
            Values
            ('Groupnameseven','GRP-7',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnameeigh','GRP-8',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnamenine','GRP-9',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1)
        End
            Else IF @mhcode='LIB'
        Begin
            insert into groups
            Values
            ('Groupnameten','GRP-10',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnameeleven','GRP-11',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1),
            ('Groupnametwelve','GRP-12',@mhID,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,getdate(),NULL,getdate(),1)
        End
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor into @mhID, @mhcode;
    close mycursor;

END
```

Comment: Please: **do NOT** use a cursor inside a trigger! That's the absolute **worst** you can do to your system! A trigger should be small, fast, nimble - a cursor isn't any of this! Avoid heavy lifting and extensive processing in a trigger - just make a note of something to do - but don't actually **do** that long running process in a trigger! That'll **KILL** your system performance! Cursors also aren't necessary - it probably 95%+ of all cases - most definitely not here!!

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor doesn't exist because you have declared it as `mycrusor` instead of `mycursor`. But I would recommend you doing this without a cursor.

There's also a severe problem with your code, you're fetching values from inserted into a variable, which doesn't work correctly when more than one row has been inserted.

and your fetch next is outside the while loop.